# Given a set and an element, can we say that the element is subset of the given set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let us consider a set $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and an element say $1$.

Can we say that  $1$ is subset of set $A$.

If not, please explain.

Comment: A set of which every element is a subset is called transitive. Unsurprisingly for something we bothered naming, transitivity is a property only of some sets. If you want to construe natural numbers as subsets of natural transitive sets, look up how we model naturals as ordinals.

Comment: Formally it depends on how $1$ is defined. If e.g. $1:=\{2\}$ (a far-fetched choice) then element $1$ is also a subset of $A$.

Comment: ...and $\{1\}$ is both an element and a subset of $\{1,\{1\},\dots\}$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, we say that

- $1$ is an element of $A$, that is $1\in A$

and

- $\{1\}$ is a subset of $A$, that is $\{1\}\subseteq A$

Answer (score 3):

$1$ can not be subset of $A$ because $1$ is not a set. We can say that a set $B$ is a subset of a set $A$ if every element of B is also element of A. For example, the sets:
$\{1, 2\}, \{2, 4, 5\}$
are subsets of A.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you explicitly *define* another set which *contains* the element 1, then we cannot say that 1 is the subset of A.

There are exceptions, however.

Let's consider an rather unlikely, but still very much possible, scenario in which we define the symbol '1' as a set with elements {2,5}. In this case, then 1 is definitely a subset of A, because 1 is now a symbol which denotes a set that contains the elements which also belongs to A (2 and 5).